# How to I render content natively in a uitextview just like medium.com?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, epub

I want to render book summaries in a way that looks properly formatted, such as medium.com does in its app. I have all the summaries in HTML format, and I'm thinking this should be as simple as feeding the HTML into a UITextView and have it display it. But UITextViews don't render HTML. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display HTML content, use [`WKWebView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview), not `UITextView`.